# How to add space betweeen ng-repeat block element?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have server logs as data using `ng-repeat` i am trying to add space using margin but its only working on last item. How can i add space between every `span` element to incoming logs.

main.css

```
.messageMargin {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

main.html

```
<ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="message in event.data track by $index" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span class="messageMargin">{{message.value}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `<span>` as a block level element so that there is a new line preceding and succeeding the `<span>`. Change your CSS to

```
.messageMargin {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

or, if `messageMargin` is used somewhere else where you do not want to make it a block level element then add the css as inline:

```
<span  class="messageMargin" style="display:block;">{{message.value}}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks setting display property to block solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `display` type of the `span`...

```
.messageMargin {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `span` element, much like anchor tags `a` are inline elements by default.

So, assigning it a `display` property can turn it into a `block` element (which will naturally take an entire row) or an `inline-block` element (which will take the same amount of space as the default `span` - but with the benefits of a block-type element, which will allow for margins and other properties that a simple `inline` element would not allow.